# iOS: UIButton touch up inside doesn't respond multiple press

Tags: ipad, uibutton, ibaction, long-press

I have a UIButton whose IBAction has been setup though XIB file. Following is the IBAction method. When I press button multiple times very quickly, this method gets called only once for the last press. I have to wait little more time between the presses. Is there anything like long press time for UIButton that I can reduce or any other settings to make it responding quicker. This button does the similar job of Keyboard's back button to delete last character. I want it to respond very quick like Keyboard's button does. Thanks.

```
- (IBAction)deleteButtonPress:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Click");
    if(self.numpadTextFiled.text.length > 0)
        self.numpadTextFiled.text = [self.numpadTextFiled.text substringToIndex:   [self.numpadTextFiled.text length]-1];
}
```

Comment: Is the button by any chance positioned within a UIScrollView? If so, then touches are delayed

Comment: no it's not in uiscrollview. it is in the UIVIew.

Comment: You have given me hint. A Button is in the UIVIew which is implementing different gestures. I have removed those gestures and then button started responding quick. Please put this as an answer. I will accept it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the button by any chance positioned within a UIScrollView? If so, then touches are delayed?